# Sorting list of dictionaries in order of value of one of the keys in a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

`a=[{'post': 3, 'value': 42}, {'post': 4, 'value': 12}, {'post': 12, 'value': 25}]`

How can I sort it to this:

`a=[{'post': 3, 'value': 42}, {'post': 12, 'value': 25}, {'post': 4, 'value': 12}]`

I mean in order to value with reverse.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `key` and `reverse` arguments:

```
result = sorted(a, key=lambda d:d["value"], reverse=True)
```

`key` must be a function that given an element of the list returns a value on which the sorting should be done. In this case the function passed is an anonymous function that given a dictionary returns the value associated to the key `"value"`.

Note that `sorted(x)` returns a sorted **copy** of the list. If you want to sort the list inplace you can just call the method `sort` of the list object passing the same parameters. Note also that `x = sorted(x)` is not equivalent to `x.sort()`.

Hopefully this is still considered reasonable Python even if contains the ugly "lambda" monster... :-)

Comment: This makes another list. I think he asked to sort the same list.

Comment: `operator.itemgetter('value')` will probably be slightly faster than the lambda (if it matters)

Comment: @MarcodeWit: He used the same variable in both "before" and "after". So may be s/he wants to sort the list inplace or may be s/he wants to do `a=a.sorted(...)` instead. I'll add a clarification.

Comment: @mgilson: here we go with lambda bashing :-) ... please however state your hate clearly (e.g. "flat is better than nested all the way down to COBOL without COMPUTE") and not using the performance excuse. If that level of speedup matters the most probably Python is a questionable choice in the first place.

Comment: @6502 -- I'm perfectly happy with the use of lambda in a lot of situations.  I don't even mind your use of it here.  I just figured that I'd point out an alternative which some people would prefer -- It's good to have to comment there because people use that idiom and it's good to know what it does in the event that you ever read someone else's code that uses it, or if you decide you like it better yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[{'post': 3, 'value': 42}, {'post': 4, 'value': 12}, {'post': 12, 'value': 25}]

a.sort(key=lambda d: -d['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a=  [{'post': 3, 'value': 42}, {'post': 12, 'value': 25}, {'post': 4, 'value': 12}]
>>> sorted(a, key=itemgetter('value'), reverse=True)
[{'post': 3, 'value': 42}, {'post': 12, 'value': 25}, {'post': 4, 'value': 12}]
```